# How do I replace string in htaccess with PHP?

Tags: php, foreach, file-get-contents, str-replace, file-put-contents

I am trying to manage blocked IPs on my server.
I list the blocked IPs from the htaccess file and would like to select the IPs that I want to allow by replacing the selected IP from the above list example `deny from 123.4.56.789` with blank space (to remove the `deny from IP` command.

I have tried everything but my code does not replace the selected IP with a blank space. The error_log does not show any errors.

Here is my code to list the IP addresses:

```
$base = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$htaccess = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/.htaccess";
$file = $htaccess;
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$lines = explode("\n", $contents); // this is your array of words
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/^deny from \d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}$/', $line)) {
        echo "<table width='50%'>
                <tr>
                    <td><r>$line</r></td>
                    <td style='text-align:left'><center><input type='checkbox' id='ipCheck' name='ipCheck' value='$ip'></center></td>
                </tr>
            </table>";
    }   
}



<!--Button below-->
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><button id="allowIPbtn" name="allowIPbtn" class='btn'>Allow selected IPs</button></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

JQuery when button is clicked:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#allowIPbtn').click(function () {
      if($("input:checkbox[name=ipCheck]").is(":checked")){
            $("input:checkbox[name=ipCheck]:checked").each(function () {
            $("#overlay").show();
            $("#overlay").delay(120000).hide(0);    
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {iplist: $(this).val()},
                        success: function(data){
                        allowIP();
                        }
                    });
        });
      }

        
    });
});

</script>
```

My attempt to replace the selected IP with a blankspace:

```
ob_start();
if(isset($_POST['iplist']) ){
    $ipSelected = $_POST['iplist'];
    $htaccess_file = $htaccess;
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($htaccess_file);

    foreach((array)$ipSelected as $selectedIP){
        $file_contents = str_replace($selectedIP, "",$file_contents);
        file_put_contents($htaccess_file,$file_contents);
        echo $ipSelected;
    }
    exit;
}
```

Sample IP list:

```
deny from 10.10.76.194
deny from 10.10.85.70
deny from 10.10.63.174
deny from 10.10.56.77
deny from 10.10.15.196
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: A site that can edit its own `.htaccess` is a huge security hole waiting to happen. Your server should never have write access to the files it serves.

Comment: What does `$_POST['iplist']` actually contain? I see you casting this into an array there, `(array)$ipSelected` - but that should not be necessary, if the value already was an array; an if it is not, then this cast probably won't achieve what you think it should. Also, why are you writing the complete file inside the loop already?

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks for the comment. I added code for more information. When the button is clicked, ajax initiate PHP.

Comment: @CBroe. The `(array)$ipSelected` was an attempt to see if it will make a difference. It was not in original code :)

Comment: What, you are making a separate AJAX request for each single checked checkbox? Why? And why did you implement a _loop_ on the server side in the first place then?

Comment: @CBroe. The list will contain multiple IP address (if any). Which loop are you referring to?

Comment: _"The list will contain multiple IP address"_ - what list? Are you talking about the `iplist` variable in your JS? That reads the value of _one_ single checkbox.

Comment: I am not talking about the first part, I am talking about your AJAX request, and the script where you try to process that.

Comment: The AJAX request is working fine. I am using the same format on another page. My issue is my script does not edit the file I wish to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference if someone has the same issue:
File_put_content and file_get_content have characters length limits.
My issue was solved by using fopen().

```
if(isset($_POST['mylist'])){
$ipSelected = $_POST['mylist'];
$root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$htFile = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/.htaccess";
$accessfile = file_get_contents($htFile);
$iplines = explode("\n", $ipSelected); // this is your array of words
foreach($iplines as $selectedIP){
    $htaccessfile = fopen($htFile, "c+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $str = str_replace($ipSelected," ",$accessfile); 
    fwrite($htaccessfile, $str);
    fclose($htaccessfile);
    echo "Done";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use `explode(" ", $line)`, to get an array like this:

```
["deny","from","123.4.56.55"]
```

So you can check the key "2" to get the IP.
You can also use this method to create a new .htaccess from scratch, storing all the lines but the line that contain the IP you like to remove

Comment: Yes... what method are you using to block access? can you put here a multiple blocked IPS example?

Comment: List added as requested :)